# Micronaut Test UnknownHostException

Tags: java, junit5, micronaut

I have some test anotated with `@MicronautTest`, and client is injected as

```java
@Inject
@Client("/")
protected HttpClient client;
```

I local it works fine, but in jenkins when these tests are run inside docker I get error

```
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientException
        Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException
```

It doesn't says anything what it is trying to access as host (localhost, 127.0.0.1 or containerid)

containers are running without network, and most probably enabling network is not an option.

how to fix this?

Comment: I am surprised that `@Client('/')` doesn't work in the container.  If you file a report at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues, we can take a look.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Done